# How to redirect using select and submit button

Tags: php, html

I'm using php to populate an option list, and then want to use a submit to and bring me to another page...how can I check what was selected in the dropdown list,submit and bring me to that page?

```
 form action="/test.php" method="post">
    <select>
    <option value hidden>All</option>
    <?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($connection,"test");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select description from categories");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   
    print "<option value = 
    ".$row['description'].".php".">".$row['description']."</option>";
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    <button type = "submit" form= "menu" value="Submit">Filter</button>`
```

Comment: You need to give your `<select>` element a `name` attribute, and then check against that in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that when you're sending options via `$_POST`, you need to give the **`<select>`** element a **[`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name)** attribute (not each `<option>`):

```
<form action="/test.php" method="post">
  <select name="description">
    <option value hidden>All</option>
    <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($connection,"test");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select description from categories");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {   
      print "<option name='some_Name' value = 
      ".$row['description'].".php".">".$row['description']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" form="menu" value="Submit">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Then you can retrieve the selected `<option>` with:

```
$_POST['description']
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to give your option element a name.

```
form action="/test.php" method="post">
    <select>
    <option value hidden>All</option>
    <?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($connection,"test");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select description from categories");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   
    print "<option name='some_Name' value = 
    ".$row['description'].".php".">".$row['description']."</option>";
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    <button type = "submit" form= "menu" value="Submit">Filter</button>`
```

then in your test.php file you can access the select using:

```
$selectOption = $_POST['some_Name'];
```